# Error while creating SQL API container on the Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I received below error message while creating new SQL API container. It's working last week.

Error creating database: "{\"code\":\"Forbidden\",\"message\":\"Message: {\\"code\\":\\"Forbidden\\",\\"message\\":\\"Message: {\\\\"Errors\\\\":[\\\\"DataBase SharedOffer is Disabled for your account, for further queries please contact support.\\\\"]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved when I created new Azure Cosmos DB Account in the UK South region. The error one was created in West UK region.